# displayTag: how to change displayTag parameters

Tags: displaytag

I want to change the ugly displayTag (tableid) parameter from `d-bunchofnumbers-p` to a URL friendly one. I also want to change the sort and page parameters as well.

Is it trivial to do this?
If so, how? Is it as simple as setting the following properties?

```
<display:setProperty name="pagination.pagenumber.param" value="page"/> 
<display:setProperty name="pagination.sort.param" value="sort"/> 
<display:setProperty name="pagination.sortdirection.param" value="dir"/>
```

The URL should look like this:

```
results?sort=id&dir=asc&page=1
```

I've tried this but, it's not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem. After binding the grid with an implementation displaytag´s PaginatedList the parameters started looking more friendly.

Have a look at [this post](http://www.jdal.org/doc/displaytag.php) to understand what I´m talking about.